# What's the equivalent of state params (Angular 1 & ui-router) in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular

In Angular 1 and ui-router I used states params a lot to pass data from one state to another (without using URL parameters). Is it possible in Angular 2?

Router, RouteParams, RouterLink and RouteData does not seem to handle this for instance I want to pass a user object from one state to another

```
<a ui-sref="home({user: myCtrl.user})">
```

this does not seem possible in Angular 2.

Comment: RouteParams plays the same role as $routeParams or $stateParams. And $stateParams **is** used to change URL path and query parameters: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#stateparams-service. Quote: *The $stateParams is a perfect way to provide your controllers or other services with the individual parts of the navigated url*.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, you could use $stateParams to retrieve data like Array or Object. Checkout the params API: http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider
"A map which optionally configures parameters declared in the url, or defines additional non-url parameters."
I am interested in the "non-url parameters"

Comment: I didn't know that was possible. But it seems like a bad idea to me anyway. If the parameters are not in the URL, refreshing the page won't work: the parameter values will be lost.

Comment: You are right, I used this feature a lot to avoid getting data from the server when navigating. This speed up your app when you have data in memory. In the case of a reload, you can retrieve your server data.
If you want to see it in action you can click on a user in this page: http://app.trendingdevs.com/world the user being already in memory going to his page is instantaneous (if you happen to open directly the user page, the data will be fetch from the server)

Comment: Ah, I see now. That can indeed be a useful optimization sometimes. The RouteParams (poor) documentation mentions "optional parameters for that route", but I don't see how you can define them. Maybe you just don't need to, and you can simply pass any parameter you want.

Comment: Wouldn't a service that caches the server data be a better pattern here?

Comment: @JBNizet If I pass an Object to the RouterLink or the Router.navigate it adds a url parameter: `domain.com/?user=[Object Object]`

Comment: @IonutCostica that's not what this question is about. Using a third party service to store the data (in memory or localstorage) could be a solution in Angular2 but I am writing an article on the comparaison of the new Router and the UI-Router so I need to know the equivalent of `params` in A2.

Answer (score -1):

If you're using Angular 2 router, you can pass the state via `@RouteParams`, for example,

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ProductDetail', {id: 1234}]">Product Details</a>
```

In this case id is your state, and it can be any object, e.g.:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/ProductDetail', myStateObject]">Product Details</a>
```

On the other hand, Angular 2 has a mechanism for passing parameters using binding to component's `@Input()` parameters, but this can be used only within the same route.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what my question is about. I am interested in the "non-url parameters". If you want to update your answer please read the comments on the question to avoid confusion.